# Magento Add to cart button not showing for not logged visitors

Tags: addtocart

Hello I'm new with the magento.

***I'm working with the 1.9.2.4 version and when I'm not logged the button add to cart doesn't appear.***

I tried to look in

```
app/design/frontend/your-theme-package/theme-variant/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

but there's nothing like

```
(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
```

Comment: it seems you are mixing magento 1 and magento 2.

Comment: in which version of Magento you are working?

Comment: Versión de Magento 1.9.2.4

Answer (score 1):

You should not look in this template

> app/design/frontend/your-theme-package/theme-variant/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml

but check this template

> app/design/frontend/your-theme-package/theme-variant/catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thak you very much.

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: Sorry but now it It does not work in the individual product view or in the grid category view like guest. I'll send the link https://libidtoys.com/nuestros-productos/cosmetica.html

Comment: They maybe have different template, best way to check which template they are using , opent template path hints for the storeview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24273443/in-magento-1-9-0-0-how-can-i-enable-template-path-hint , and open the template that shows those to make the update . I suggest to try that in a develop website before proceeding to production .